# CSS Footer color! Can`t change it!

Tags: css, colors, footer

I'm trying to change the footer color for my site. I've tried everything, but it does not seem to work!

Here's the link for my CSS: http://pp.atoanavida.com.br/style2.css
Here's the page: http://pp.atoanavida.com.br

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the floated elements inside `#footer-content`.

An easy way to do this is to add `overflow: hidden` to the CSS for `#footer-content`.

I recommend you read an article like this one, to learn more: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Answer (score 2):

You got some invalid css in your code.

Under `#footer`, change `background: { #77aadd !important;}` to:

either `background: #77aadd !important;`

or `background-color: #77aadd !important;`

**edit**

In your HTML, add `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` right before closing the `<div id="footer">` (right after closing `<div id="footer-content">`).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice you'd updated your answer to include a way to clear floats. Have a consolatory +1 :)

Comment: @thirtydot all that matters is that he got a working answer :)

Comment: @thirtydot, @Niklas: Thanks to you all. Guess i`m too stupid to understand what you told me to do, but it worked =)

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
#footer {
    clear: both;
    background: { #77aadd !important;}
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    font: normal .95em/1.5em 'Tahoma', Trebuchet MS, Sans-serif;
    width:100%;


}
```

with

```
#footer {
    clear: both;
    background-color:  #77aadd !important;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    font: normal .95em/1.5em 'Tahoma', Trebuchet MS, Sans-serif;
    width:100%;


}
```

`#footer-content` also has the same problem with syntax, replace

```
#footer-content {   
    border-top: 0px solid #EAEAEA;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 15px auto;   
    background: { #77aadd !important;} 
    width:100%; 
}
```

with

```
#footer-content {   
    border-top: 0px solid #EAEAEA;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 15px;   
    background-color: #77aadd !important; 
    width:100%; 
}
```